# Unexpected behavior of the `find` function in Common-Lisp

Tags: search, common-lisp

Searching for `nil` in a sequence using `find` always returns `NIL`.

```
(find nil #(a b nil c)) -> NIL

(find nil #(a b c)) -> NIL
```

Same thing if the sequence is a list.

However, `member` operates as I would expect:

```
(member nil '(a b nil c)) -> (NIL C)
```

Why was `find` designed to operate this way?

Note that `position` works as I would expect:

```
(position nil #(a b nil c)) -> 2

(position nil #(a b c)) -> NIL
```

Comment: have you looked into the specification of FIND? It returns the element if found, or NIL if there is none. If you search for NIL, then it returns one if there is one, Otherwise it returns NIL. It thus means that FIND is more useful when you search for something other than NIL. MEMBER and POSITION are doing something different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[FIND](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_find_.htm#find) simply isn't useful if the target element is NIL. It's returning the found element, but it's indistinguishable from the not-found case. If you want to find out of a sequence has a nil, [POSITION](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_pos_p.htm#position) is a better option. There are many other options.

Answer (score 1):

It returns nil because the result of find if the element is not in the sequence is nil. But even with member, if it is not in the sequence, it will return nil:

```
CL-USER> (member nil '(a b c))
NIL
CL-USER>
```

So technically searching for nil in a sequence will return nil with member and position if it isn't there which can be confusing of course.

```
CL-USER> (position nil '(a b c))
NIL
CL-USER>
```

The difference with position is that if nil occurs, it will return the index location of course, as you noted. Find was designed that way because it is NOT searching for an index location, but is essentially searching to match the pointer for that symbol, or return nil. That's why using position makes more sense, as you've noted.